# PowerPC boots and freezes

Tags: mac, freeze, powerpc

My friend is using a PowerPC which he has maintained well over the years. Today, it fails to finish booting and freezes on boot attempts. He tells me the following:

> "It was operating just fine then it froze up. This almost never
>   happens. I had to force quit. Now it will not restart. I get the bong
>   then the Apple  and the rotating clock. The clock finally stops and
>   the computer cooling fan comes on"

And ideas on where to start to fix this?

He said his harddrive is not full (to his knowledge) and he has dusted it out inside periodically.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which version of OSX (or perhaps OS8 or OS9) it is. Should also try a [Linux LiveCD that supports PPC](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/5.04/).

Comment: Yeah I'm going to get him a PPC Ubuntu CD and see if it boots...that'll at least tell us if it's a harddrive issue. He's on OS X Leopard, 10.5.8.

Comment: Have him try a [verbose boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) (hold Command and V at startup until text appears on screen) and see if that gives any indication what's going wrong (or if it even boots far enough to display any text).